# Library doesn't properly link at command 'make'

Tags: makefile, petsc

I am trying to use some open-source `CFD` code, and it uses `PETSC` and some other libraries, so I installed them. But when I try to compile program useing 'make', it seems like libraries are not properly linked with makefile

[image]

[image]

It seems like petsc isn't properly linked, but I can't know why...

Comment: Please edit your question and include your Makefile and error as text.

Comment: You are missing a link to an X11 library, i.e. `-lX11` appended to your lib flags, but it also looks like you are using petsc version 3.1-p6, which is almost a decade old. Can you try upgrading to latest release and see if the issue persists?

Comment: I used 3.1 because the code wanted me to use the decade old version. However, the problem is solved. I asked to developer and he answered that the code doesn't really need X11. So I excluded option using x11 while installing petsc, and the problem is solved. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that PETSc depends on some more libraries (X11) than the CFD package counted on. It should have a proper configure that figures these out. However, you can get the link line you need using

```
cd PETSC_DIR; make getlinklibs
```

which you can then put in LIBFLAG.